GPT2 conversion to Tensorflow Lite example from official TF git fails
Following the instructions in the Generative AI sample Tensorflow repo I am facing many errors. Below is one of the errors from chatGPT history but don't I have the exact code that generated it because every time I managed to fix one, I ran into another and I lost track.
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:1) to a numpy array
On Windows, my research on the error (different one) got me to this post which states that keras_nlp runs only on Debian. As a result, I have installed Debian on a VM and continued to test there.
I tried to downgrade keras, keras_nlp and tensorflow to a version just before May 2023, when the readme was added to git. More errors.
My goal:
At the end of the day, I need to get the autocomplete.tflite file to use in Android. The file is not available for download, as it was for other sample repos I tried (e.g. BERT QA, Smart Reply)
I want to test the Generative AI Android sample, to get a better understanding of its capabilities and use it in my app. Gradle downloads an AAR file, but it doesn't have the tflite file included. The Android sample code errors on loading the model file val descriptor = context.assets.openFd(TFLITE_MODEL)
This is the code, essentially just copied the readme instructions for steps 1 and 2:
import keras_nlp
import tensorflow as tf

gpt2_tokenizer = keras_nlp.models.GPT2Tokenizer.from_preset("gpt2_base_en")

gpt2_preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
  "gpt2_base_en",
  sequence_length=256,
  add_end_token=True,
)

gpt2_lm = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLM.from_preset(
  "gpt2_base_en", 
  preprocessor=gpt2_preprocessor,
)

@tf.function
def generate(prompt, max_length):
  # prompt: input prompt to the LLM in string format
  # max_length: the max length of the generated tokens 
  return gpt2_lm.generate(prompt, max_length)
concrete_func = generate.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec([], tf.string), 100)

def run_inference(input, generate_tflite):
  interp = interpreter.InterpreterWithCustomOps(
    model_content=generate_tflite,
    custom_op_registerers=tf_text.tflite_registrar.SELECT_TFTEXT_OPS)
  interp.get_signature_list()

  generator = interp.get_signature_runner('serving_default')
  output = generator(prompt=np.array([input]))

gpt2_lm.jit_compile = False
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions(
  [concrete_func],
  gpt2_lm)

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TFLite ops
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, # enable TF ops
]
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
converter.target_spec.experimental_select_user_tf_ops = [
  "UnsortedSegmentJoin",
  "UpperBound"
]
converter._experimental_guarantee_all_funcs_one_use = True
generate_tflite = converter.convert()
run_inference("I'm enjoying a", generate_tflite)

